# How to put labels for only the first and the last value of a series in R and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data in CSV

```
Date,Timestamp,Bugs overall,Open overall,Enhancements,Actual bugs,Needinfo,Workable bugs,Bugs with patch
2016-03-13 22:40,1457905248276,3626,454,91,363,113,250,6
2016-03-29 21:31,1459279868888,3642,453,91,362,118,244,7
2016-04-06 21:55,1459972517328,3652,447,92,355,116,239,7
2016-04-10 07:30,1460266206486,3655,446,93,353,116,237,9
...
```

I load the data, convert it using melt() and then plot it as follows

```
library(parsedate)
data <- read.csv("stats.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep=",", quote="")

library(reshape2)
datam <- melt(data, id.vars="Date", measure.vars=
    # when you change the order here also adjust it below for the legent
    c("Open.overall","Actual.bugs","Workable.bugs","Needinfo","Enhancements","Bugs.with.patch"))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(datam, aes(x=parse_date(Date, approx = TRUE), y=value, colour=variable)) +
    # draw lines with dots and inner white-circles to get a "subway map"-like effect
    geom_line(size = 2) +
    geom_point(size = 3) +
    geom_point(size = 1.50, color = "white") +
    # add fitted regression lines
    geom_smooth(data=subset(datam, parse_date(Date, approx = TRUE) >= parse_date("2015-08-10 10:21")), 
                            method="lm", level=0.99, linetype="dashed") +
    # pin the y-axis at zero
    expand_limits(y=0) +
    # start after the change in how we compute the values, it's actually at 2015-08-10 10:21
    #xlim(parse_date("2015-08-19 00:00"), max(parse_date(datam$Date, approx = TRUE))) +
    # specify the label for both axes
    xlab("Date") +
    ylab("Number of issues") +
    # add more ticks on the y-axis
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1000,by=100)) +
    # set a title for the graph
    ggtitle("Open bugs in Apache POI") + 
    # set the default black/white theme
    theme_bw() +
    # legend styling
    theme(legend.position="right",
          legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
    scale_colour_discrete(labels=
        # this list needs to match the order used above!
        c("Open","Bugs","Workable Bugs","Needinfo","Enhancements","Bugs with Patch")) +
    guides(colour=guide_legend(title=NULL))
```

Which results in a nice chart

[image]

Now I would like to add data-labels but only for the first and last item in each series so that the chart is not cluttered with numbers, but still indicates the starting points and the current states.

I saw that there is geom_text() and geom_label(), but I could not find how to only apply them for the first and last item in each series.

I would like to avoid using fixed dates for this, as the underlying data is updated from time to time with newer values.

Comment: check the directlabels package

Comment: You may also find `annotate` from `ggplot2` useful.

Comment: You can also construct a column that holds labels and have NAs for all but first and last entry.

Comment: I have achieved good results with package `ggrepel` to avoid overlapping text labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `data.frame` with exact same structure as the one you are using in plot but only with first and last elements you want to show as label. Use this `data.frame` for `geom_label` and map your `labels` asthetics with the `value`.

Comment: I could give working example if you have provided a reproducible situation.

Comment: I have updated the question with the full R-code, is that enough to provide a full working example? Or at least the rought steps?

Comment: With some more searching I was able to put together a fairly good solution of the problem. Thanks for the hint!